# Extra white space in bar diagram matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating the following plot and it seems like it's leaving some extra white space on the right hand side and I'm not exactly sure why.

[image]

The code to generate the above is given below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = (0,1,3,6,4,2,2,59,4,3,4,4,33,3,2,5,61)
d2 = (6,7,9,4,4,4,3,19,4,1,11,28,13,8,15,28,28)
d3 = (6,7,9,4,4,4,3,19,4,1,14,28,13,8,15,28,32)

N = len(d1)
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.2

font = {'family' : 'sans-serif', 'weight' : 'normal', 'size' : 10}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, MA_DPU, width, color='r', alpha=0.7)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, res1, width, color='b', alpha=0.7)
rects3 = ax.bar(ind+2*width, res2, width, color='g', alpha=0.7)

ax.set_xticks(ind+width*1.5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the `xlim` of your `Axes`:

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 16.4)
plt.show()
```

For convenience you can use ["plt.autoscale()"](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

```
plt.autoscale()
```

avoiding to set the `xlim` manually.

The optional parameters with their default values are:

`plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)`

Comment: That worked great, do you have any idea why it generated that by default?  I'm just surprised it happened at all

Comment: I've updated the answer adding some comments about `autoscale`